# Disabling WebJob Functions Depending on Environment

Tags: c#, app-config, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

My team recently inherited an ASP.NET solution that runs on Azure App Services. One project in the solution seems to define C# code that leverages the Azure WebJobs SDK to run several functions. I am not a C# or ASP.NET developer by trade, but I'm involved in developing the build and release pipelines for the project.

I have two App Service environments that need to run the WebJobs project, but in the case of one of those environments, some of the functions should **not** run.

Each function seems to have its own .cs file, and it seems these functions can inherit configuration from an App.config file (which can be transformed at runtime using files like App.Staging.config and App.Prod.config). An example of a function in the project might look like:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace My.Project.WebJobs
{
    public class SomeTask
    {
        public void ExecuteTask([TimerTrigger(typeof(CustomScheduleDaily3AM))]TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
        {

            var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
            var SomeSetting = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeSetting"]);


        unitOfWork.Execute.Something();
    }
}
```

}

With my limited understanding of my options, the first idea that occurred to me was to potentially add an enable/disable switch to the method(s) (i.e. SomeTask or ExecuteTask in the example above) that might read its true/false value from a setting defined in App.config. Though, not being well-versed in C#... I'm not confident this is possible. Doing it this way, the function may still run, but no action is taken on account of the method(s) being disabled.

I feel as if there may be a solution that relies more on Azure configuration as opposed to function-level code changes. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After researching, I found three ways to meet your need.

1. Create multiple instance depends on different environment, and publish your WebJobs to different instance.
2. Use staging slots.
3. Use 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT' appsettings. I would show how below:

Configure the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` on portal. (This setting was in launchSettings.json file in local machine)

Modify your code like this (just for showing how it works, more info see the doc):

```
if (_env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_env.EnvironmentName); //modify with your function
    }
    else if (_env.IsStaging())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_env.EnvironmentName); //modify with your function
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not dev or staging"); //modify with your function
    }
```

Here is a reference about [Use multiple Environments in ASPNET CORE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0),